# DHTML URL portion automatically dissects when running onto server

Tags: email, url, server, query-string, dhtml

- When I run URL requests from this onto my browser then it works finely.
  And, gives me the desired response.

> {{ocx_feed_dynamic_html{url=http://demo.projects.stepinsolutions.in/og_tests_assets/dynamic_feed_creator/get-dynamic-feed-clone.php?key={{city}}&feed_type=html}}}

- But, when I send a test mail and it has to get a response from the server it will automatically remove some portion of the URL. And, it will parse as mentioned below.

> {{ocx_feed_dynamic_html{url=http://demo.projects.stepinsolutions.in/og_tests_assets/dynamic_feed_creator/get-dynamic-feed-clone.php}}}

As a result Query string=" " remains empty while running this URL onto the server.

And at the end, I receive an email that says "Invalid feed_type or feed_type not provided!!" as an output.

Could anyone help me why it's happening? And how could I resolve this issue?